# How to use Different Button in bootstrap Form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I  have used Bootstrap and created form.my form Looks like

```
<form action="default_results.php"   method="post" class="calculator"  name="frmCalculator">
```

I have used this code in the beginning of my code and end of the page I have used three button Looks like

```
              <div class="row">

                            <button id="button2" class="dont-compare shadow-inset" value="reset" >
                                    Reset</button>
                            <button id="button3" data-toggle="pop" class="dont-compare shadow-inset" class="update" >
                                    Update MI</button>
                            <button id="Button4"  class="dont-compare shadow-inset" class="calculator" >
                                    Calculate Scenarios</button>
              </div>
```

I  have another page its called default_ results.php page. I want to load that page when I click Calculate Scenarios button.I have used `href tag` for that button. But that three button also load default_results page.

How to set particular button?  please any idea about it?

Comment: please mention type="submit" on button you make normle button now

Comment: where i assign type ?

Comment: in button tag you can mention to submit the form

Comment: i am not clear @Dharmendra

Comment: <button id="Button4"  class="dont-compare shadow-inset" class="calculator" type="submit" >
                                    Calculate Scenarios</button>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not about bootstrap, but HTML. Default type for buttons is submit. When you want only one button should submit the form, add them explicity `type="submit"` and to the others add `type="button"`.
For example `button4` will submit forms, other redirect on click.

```
<button type="button" onclick="location.href = '/some_page_1.php';" id="button2" class="dont-compare shadow-inset" value="reset" >Reset</button>
<button type="button" id="button3" data-toggle="pop" class="dont-compare shadow-inset" class="update" >Update MI</button>
<button type="submit" id="button4" class="dont-compare shadow-inset" class="calculator" >Calculate Scenarios</button>
```

or more elegant way to redirect:

```
<script>
   document.getElementById("button3").onclick = function () {
        location.href = "/some_page_2.php";
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because your button is in the form,

you can make (in Jquery or Javascript) :

```
$('#Button').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

To avoid the form post.

And after make :

```
window.location.href('your_url');
```

To redirect browser to your url

Answer (score -1):

use this css class with buttons through php if condition

```
.hide {
 display: none;
}
```

Comment: This is not related to question.